# Javascript Object Syntax Error when declaring function

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'drive'. Expected '}' to end an object literal. (line 9)
```

It seems to suggest an extra '}' but I can't spot it, or figure out if anything else might be wrong. I am relatively new to JavaScript so any help will be appreciated. Please see code below.

Thanks!

```
var taxi = {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Taxi",
    year: 1955,
    colour: "yellow",
    passengers: 4,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 281341
    drive: funtion() {
        alert("Voom Voom");
    }
};

function prequal(car) {
    if (car.mileage > 10000 || car.year > 1960) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var worthALook = prequal(taxi);

if (worthALook) {
    console.log("Check it out! " + taxi.make + " " + taxi.model);
}
else {
    console.log("Not worth! " + taxi.make + " " + taxi.model);  
}

taxi.drive();
```

Comment: you need a comma after `mileage: 281341`. Also, function is misspelled as `funtion`

Comment: Thanks! It was the function typo ... for some reason my text editor correctly highlighted the typo which is why I missed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma in line 8, separating `taxi.mileage` and `taxi.drive`. You've also spelled 'function' incorrectly on line 9.

Fixing those, it seems to work fine:

```js
var taxi = {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Taxi",
    year: 1955,
    colour: "yellow",
    passengers: 4,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 281341,
    drive: function() {
        alert("Voom Voom");
    }
};

function prequal(car) {
    if (car.mileage > 10000 || car.year > 1960) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var worthALook = prequal(taxi);

if (worthALook) {
    console.log("Check it out! " + taxi.make + " " + taxi.model);
}
else {
    console.log("Not worth! " + taxi.make + " " + taxi.model);  
}

taxi.drive();
```

Comment: Thanks :) I missed the function typo.